# when incrementing my static variable inside the class it's doubled when i print it out

Tags: java

So i have this homework assignment and I'm almost finished with it except I have one kink thats driving me nuts.  I know the whole thing looks a little funny but I'm going by the directions on the homework.  Anyways, Part of the work is to create a static variable named count in the Course class that keeps track of how many courses have been registered.  Heres my code (4 different classes)

Main

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentBody 
{

public static void main (String[] args)
{

  int numStudents= 0;
  int outer = 0;

  int amtCourses = 0;
  String fNameHolder;
  String lNameHolder;
  String addressHolder;
  String cityHolder;
  String stateHolder;
  String termHolder;
  String courseNumHolder;
  String locationHolder;
  String instructorHolder;
  long zipCodeHolder = 0;

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("How many students will you be inputting into the system?  ");
  numStudents = scan.nextInt();
  scan.nextLine();


  Student newJoins[] = new Student[numStudents];

  while (outer < newJoins.length)
  {
     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("First name of student: ");
     fNameHolder = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Last name of student: ");
     lNameHolder = scan.nextLine();


     System.out.print("Enter Student Home Street Address: ");
     addressHolder = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter Student Home City: ");
     cityHolder = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter Student Home State: ");
     stateHolder = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter Student Home Zip Code: ");
     zipCodeHolder = scan.nextInt();
     scan.nextLine();

     //Create an address object for the students home using the information aquired     above.  This will later
     //be used in the instantiation of the student object.                  
     Address tempHome = new Address(addressHolder, cityHolder, stateHolder, zipCodeHolder);

     System.out.print("Enter Student School Street Address: ");
     addressHolder = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter Student School City: ");
     cityHolder = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter Student School State: ");
     stateHolder = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter Student School Zip Code: ");
     zipCodeHolder = scan.nextInt();
     scan.nextLine();

     //Create an address object for the school using the information aquired above.  This will later
     //be used in the instantiation of the student object.
     Address tempSchool = new Address(addressHolder, cityHolder, stateHolder, zipCodeHolder);

     System.out.print("How many courses will the student be taking?");
     amtCourses = scan.nextInt();
     scan.nextLine();

     //Initialize an array to hold course objects which when the array is filled it will be used
     //to create a student object
     Course temp[] = new Course[amtCourses];

     int inner = 0;
     while(inner < temp.length)
     {
        System.out.print("Enter Term: ");
        termHolder = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Course Number: ");
        courseNumHolder = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Location: ");
        locationHolder = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Instructor: ");
        instructorHolder = scan.nextLine();

        //Fill the course array with the courses which will later be used to create the student object
        temp[inner] = new Course(termHolder, courseNumHolder, locationHolder, instructorHolder);
        Course.count++;
        inner++;

     }//End inner while loop

     newJoins[outer] = new Student(fNameHolder, lNameHolder, tempHome, tempSchool, temp);
     System.out.print(newJoins[outer] + "\n");
     for(int i = 0; i < amtCourses; i++)
     {
        System.out.print(temp[i] + "\n");
     }
     outer++;




  }//End outer while loop

  System.out.println("Number of students entered: " + numStudents);
  System.out.println("Number of courses for all students: " + Course.count);
  for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
  {
     System.out.println(i + " " + newJoins[i].getFname() + " " + newJoins[i].getLname());
  }

}//end main
}//end StudentBody
```

This is the Course Class

```
class Course
{
   private String Term, courseNumber, Location, Instructor;
   static int count = 0;

public Course(String cTerm, String cCourseNumber, String cLocation, String cInstructor)
{
  Term = cTerm;
  courseNumber = cCourseNumber;
  Location = cLocation;
  Instructor = cInstructor;
  count++;
}

//Get Methods
public String getTerm()
{
  return Term;
}

public String getCourseNumber()
{
  return courseNumber;
}

public String getLocation()
{
  return Location;
}

public String getInstructor()
{
  return Instructor;
}

//Set Methods
public void setTerm(String set)
{
  Term = set;
}

public void setCourseNumber(String set)
{
  courseNumber = set;
}

public void setLocation(String set)
{
  Location = set;
}

public void setInstructor(String set)
{
  Instructor = set;
}

public String toString()
{
  return "Term: " + Term + "\t" + "Course Num: " + courseNumber + "\t" + "Location: " +      Location + "\t" + "Instructor: " + Instructor;
}
}
```

So for some reason when i print out the count variable in the end it's double the value that it should be.

If for some reason you need to see the other classes let me know.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What should it be and what is it?

Comment: Is it your count variable?

Comment: You should make `count` private and write a getter to prevent classes that shouldn't write to `count` from accidentally writing to it. (This would yield a compile time error if you try to compile the StudentBody class). See vandale's answer for the code lines, that write to `count`.

Comment: I agree but the homework assignment specifically asked for the way it's coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing the count in 2 places each time yo create a new `Course`. Simply removing one will fix the issue.

```
//Fill the course array with the courses which will later be used to create the student object
    temp[inner] = new Course(termHolder, courseNumHolder, locationHolder, instructorHolder);
    Course.count++;
```

and

```
public Course(String cTerm, String cCourseNumber, String cLocation, String cInstructor)
{
  Term = cTerm;
  courseNumber = cCourseNumber;
  Location = cLocation;
  Instructor = cInstructor;
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  I guess staring at it for so long confused the crap outta me.  =)